# Mount Google Storage on OS X

Tags: macos, google-cloud-storage

Can anyone suggest a way to mount [Google Storage](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/) on OS X?

I have found software Interarchy, which theoretically does allow to do that. But in practice this feature is not yet supported.

Comment: Too bad, though [Google Docs File System (gdocsfs)](http://code.google.com/p/gdocsfs/) (if related at all) is available for FUSE, I cannot (yet) find something similar for [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/).

Comment: Yesterday I have found this thing called Google-storage-fs https://github.com/richizo/google-storage-fs but I have no idea if that is what I am looking or how to use it since there is no documentation and it is Python.

Comment: Nice, @Guy. See [its README](https://github.com/richizo/google-storage-fs/blob/master/README). But when peeking into the code, it seems to rely on FUSE too.

Comment: I did look at the read me, doc. However, I have no idea how to follow it. That is, I have downloaded macfuse, installed it. Then I have downloaded the latter script, extracted, used Terminal to `cd` directory where the script is located and tried writing `gsfs.py -f gsfs.ini /mnt/GoogleStorage` which did result in error of undefined script, command or something like that.